# ng-model naming issue, trying to build an array but got hash instead

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to build an array with ng-model,

```
<div ng-repeat="n in [1, 2, 3]">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="headers[$index].key">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="headers[$index].value">
</div>
```

When I do `angular.toJson ($scope.headers)`, I got:

```
{
  "headers": {
    "0": {
      "key": "xxx",
      "value": "yyy"
    }
  }
}
```

But I wanted this,

```
{
  "headers": [
    {
      "key": "xxx",
      "value": "yyy"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is it impossible to get that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'build an array with ng-model'. Normally you have some data and you assign it the ng-model directive. ng-modal doesn't do any building as such. How does the data appear in your controller?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean?

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/aeM9ZXOygh9rHE0iXCkY?p=preview)

index.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.2/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.2"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="object in transformedData">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="object.key">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="object.value">
    </div>

    <pre>{{transformedData}}</pre>
  </body>

</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  var data = {
    "headers": {
      "0": {
        "key": "xxx",
        "value": "yyy"
      }
    }
  };

  $scope.transformedData = transformData(data.headers)

  function transformData(data){
    var arr = [];
    for(var key in data){
      arr.push(data[key])
    }
    return arr;
  }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to initialize your `header` as an array and `ng-model` assignments will work.

I have altered the plunker shared by @Matt, check it here

http://plnkr.co/edit/z6Cz6R3gZpDCsXSUmIEG?p=preview

Comment: Oh, so you substituted `$index` with number `n`, that did the trick, I guess $index is not a numeric value